# Kohain going into the Mearas HaMachpela

Tags: eretz-yisrael, cemetery-grave, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, kohen-priest

Is a Kohain allowed to enter the [Mearas HaMachpela](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cave_of_the_Patriarchs)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://www.ravaviner.com/2009/02/cohanim-and-kivrei-tzaddikim-graves-of.html

> In Iturei Cohanim (Sivan 5766 #261),
>   Rav Aviner was asked, is it
>   permissible for a cohain to enter
>   Ma’arat Ha-Machpelah? He answered that
>   there is a dispute, but Maran Ha-Rav
>   Kook did not enter. Similarly, in the
>   weekly parashah sheet "Olam Katan"
>   (#169), Rav Aviner was asked, is it
>   permissible for a cohain to enter
>   Ma’arat Ha-Machpelah to recite
>   Selichot? He answered that there is a
>   dispute, but Maran Ha-Rav Kook did not
>   enter. In Shut She’eilat Shlomo (vol.
>   3 #329), Rav Aviner also writes that
>   although there are authorities who
>   permit cohanim to enter "Kivrei
>   Tzaddikim," since the righteous are
>   called "living even in their death,"
>   the accepted halachah is that it is
>   forbidden. There are also authorities
>   who allow cohanim to visit Maarat
>   Ha-Machpelah and Kever Rachel, because
>   they were built in a way that the
>   cohanim would not become impure; but
>   the acceptable halachah for this is
>   also that it is forbidden. Therefore,
>   we say that cohanim should not enter
>   "Kivrei Tzaddikim," but we can defend
>   the practice of those who act in this
>   way, especially entering Maarat
>   Ha-Machpelah and Kever Rachel.

Comment: Is "Maran Ha-Rav Kook" referring to the father (R' Avraham Yitzchak) or the son (R' Tzvi Yehudah)? If it's the former, then frankly that's not much proof - the Arabs didn't allow Jews into the Me'arah in his days.

Answer (score 2):

Rav Ovadia (Yechaveh Daat 4:58) was opposed, but [Rav Mordechai Eliyahu](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T-1ROKnTk9E&ab_channel=%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%93%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95) and Rav Dov Lior argued the structure obstructs any Tuma from going up. See [Rav Dov Lior](https://www.yeshiva.org.il/ask/15683)'s [Devar Chevron Yoreh Deah 210](http://www.shut-halacha.co.il/q/%D7%9B%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%A1%D7%AA-%D7%9B%D7%94%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%9B%D7%A4%D7%9C%D7%94-1289?category=124), [Taharat Sdeh HaMachpelah](https://www.rabanim.org/product-page/%D7%98%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%AA-%D7%A9%D7%93%D7%94-%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%9B%D7%A4%D7%9C%D7%94), [Rav Shlomo Dichovsky in HaMaayan 235 (Tishri 5781)](https://www.machonso.org/hamaayan/?gilayon=59&id=1738), [Otzar Forums](https://forum.otzar.org/viewtopic.php?t=42655), and [this shiur](https://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/1015656/%20Mordechai%20Djavaheri/Kohanim%20Entering%20Me%27arat%20HaMachpela) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

As I remember there is part they are allowed, but not near the tombs.

---

EDIT:
here are some links on the topic:
[first](http://www.machpela.com/essay.asp?pageid=33&id=14), [second](http://www.machpela.com/events.asp?pageid=73&CurrPage=12)

Comment: Is it clearly marked?